# Apex class is called in a trigger based on some conditions.Test class passes the test but code coverage is stil 0%

Tags: apex

When work order updates to Completed then a new water meter reading record needs to created with two field values from work order and two from another object att. Both work order and water meter reading have a look up(workorder) and master detail relation(water meter reading) with att.Sorry for so much code,but I am really stuck and need help.

```
trigger CreateWaterMeterReading on sm1e__smWork_Order__c (after update) 

{   
 if (Trigger.new.size() == 1) 
 {
 sm1e__smWork_Order__c wo = Trigger.new[0];
 if(wo.sm1e__WO_Type__c == 'Meter Read Move In/Out ' && wo.sm1e__Status__c == 'Completed')
 reateNewWaterMeterRead.createWMRforMoveInOrOut(wo.Id);
   }
}
--Apex class


 public class CreateNewWaterMeterRead {

 public static void createWMRforMoveInOrOut(string workorderId)
 {
   Work_Order__c wo = [Select          Equipment__r.Name,Completion_Date__c,Meter_Reading__c from             Work_Order__c where Id = : workorderId ];
        Equipment__c att = [Select Id,Last_Water_Meter_Reading_Date__c,Last_Water_Meter_Reading__c from Equipment__c where Name = : wo.Equipment__r.Name ];

        List<Water_Meter_Readings__c> newwmr = new List<Water_Meter_Readings__c>();
         Water_Meter_Readings__c wmr = new Water_Meter_Readings__c();
        wmr.Meter__c = att.Id;
        wmr.Current_Meter_Reading__c = wo.Meter_Reading__c;
        wmr.Current_Read_Date__c = wo.sm1e__Completion_Date__c;
        wmr.Prior_Meter_Reading__c = att.Last_Water_Meter_Reading__c;
        wmr.Prior_Read_Date__c = att.Last_Water_Meter_Reading_Date__c;
        wmr.Source__c = 'Manual Read';
        newwmr.add(wmr);
        if(newwmr.size() >0)
             insert newwmr;
             }
```

--Test Class

```
isTest(SeeAllData = true)
public class CreateNewWaterMeterReadTest 
{
   static testmethod void createWMRforMoveInOrOut()
   {

        Work_Order__c wo = [Select Id,Equipment__r.Name,Completion_Date__c,Meter_Reading__c from Work_Order__c where sm1e__Status__c != 'Completed' AND sm1e__WO_Type__c = 'Meter Read Move In/Out' LIMIT 1];
        Equipment__c att = [Select Id,Last_Water_Meter_Reading_Date__c,Last_Water_Meter_Reading__c from Equipment__c where Name = : wo.Equipment__r.Name ]; 

        test.startTest();
        wo.Meter_Reading__c = 1317;
        wo.sm1e__Status__c = 'Completed';
        update wo;
        test.stopTest();
        System.debug('updated wo');

        Water_Meter_Readings__c wmr = new Water_Meter_Readings__c();
        System.debug('wmr for test');
        wmr.Meter__c= att.Id;
        wmr.Current_Meter_Reading__c = wo.Meter_Reading__c;
        wmr.Current_Read_Date__c = wo.Completion_Date__c;
        System.debug('in between wmr');
        wmr.Prior_Meter_Reading__c = att.Last_Water_Meter_Reading__c;
        wmr.Prior_Read_Date__c = att.Last_Water_Meter_Reading_Date__c;
        wmr.Source__c = 'Manual';
        insert wmr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written trigger on after update. But in your test class you're inserting a record and not updating it. That is why your code coverage is 0%. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820819/test-class-for-inserting-contacts-through-the-following-class/41844437#41844437)

For executing trigger you must do dml operation for which you've written a trigger. Also you can invoke your class method from test class by creating its instance. Refer above link for the same.